# How do I get a C++ program to count the number of words as a user enters input?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a program that keeps taking input from the user until the user enters "quit." Each time the user enters input, I want the program to print out the number of words the user has entered. So the following input on the user's part:

```
hello how are you
```

would yield the following output:

```
You entered 4 words.
```

However, I am having trouble writing the program so that it counts the number of words on just one line; it doesn't clear the number before going onto the next line. So, if it took input from the user three times, it would add up the total number of words on those three lines. For example, the following input:

```
how are you
i am good thank you
quit
```

would yield the following output:

```
 You entered 9 words.
```

when I want it to output the number of words following each line the user enters (except quit), i.e.

```
>>how are you
<<You entered 3 words.
>>i am good thank you
<<You entered 5 words.
>>quit
```

Here's the relevant bit of my code:

```
char *input;
int inum;

int inputLoop()
{
    char quit[] = "quit";
    inum = 0; //counts number of words

    while (strcmp(input, quit) != 0)
    {
         cin >> input;
         inum++;
    }
    cout <<"You entered " <<inum <<" words." <<endl;
```

I'd rather not use something like a vector; whatever I use will need to be converted to a *char eventually because my global variable is a *char. (And my global variable is a *char because, depending on certain conditions, *input may be set to *argv[] from main.)

I've tried all sorts of things, but I just can't seem to get past the fact that strcmp(input, quit) compares one word of the input at a time to quit rather than comparing the entire input line to quit. HELP.

Answer (score 5):

None of your requirements precludes the use of `std::string` and `std::vector`. I recommend you use them.

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> words;

int inputLoop()
{
    char quit[] = "quit";
    total_words = 0;

    std::string line;
    // grab a line at a time
    while(std::getline(std::cin, line) && line != quit) {
        // clear the vector of words
        words.clear();
        // make a string stream to read words from that line
        std::stringstream ss(line);
        // grab all the words into a vector
        std::string word;
        while(ss >> word) {
             words.push_back(word);
        }
        std::cout <<"You entered " <<words.size() <<" words." <<endl;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    // get the data from argv
    words = std::vector<std::string>(argv, argv + argc);
}
```

Comment: Beautiful; this looks like exactly what I want. The only problem is that now I get the following error message:

    `error: no match for operator>> in ss >> words`

Comment: I don't see any `ss >> words` in this answer. Are you sure you copied it correctly?

Comment: (I'm assuming you meant `ss >> word` to be `ss >> words`)

Comment: Why would you do that? He didn't mean that at all... although there should be an extra `std::string word;` declared in the outer `while` loop that appears to be missing.

Comment: Oh, ok, I assumed that because I didn't see the extra `std::string word` declared. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should use [getline()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/) to get an entire line of input into some buffer.  Then, process that buffer of input to count the number of words in it.  Assuming you define each word to be a block of characters separated by a space.  Myself, I am a fan of [strtok()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/) for breaking up a buffer.

Comment: @DeadMG: He suggested `getline` by the way. And `strtok` is perfectly fine in C, as long as you know that it is not thread-safe.

Comment: @netcoder: Except `strtok` requires a mutable C-style string, and there's no sensible way to get one from a C++ `std::string`. It's also not thread-safe - this may or may not be an issue for the OP's particular situation, but makes it unusable in general.

Comment: I downvoted for a perfectly good reason, and clearly stated what that reason was. It's completely constructive.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I was assuming he wasn't using `std::string`.  Why would I do something so silly, because I like `char *`'s

Comment: @CatShoes: You linked to a reference to [`std::getline()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/), which reads into a `std::string`. If you meant [`std::istream::getline()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/), then you can't read an entire line with that - you have to choose an arbitrary buffer size and handle the case of truncation. `std::string` and `std::stringstream` would be much more straightforward for those who don't want their C++ to look like an entirely different language.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach, just for fun:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    unsigned num = 0;
    std::for_each(
        std::istream_iterator<std::string>(std::cin),
        std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),

        [&num](const std::string& s)
        {
            if (s == "quit")
                std::cin.setstate(std::ios::eofbit);
            ++num;
            if (std::cin.peek() == '\n') {
                std::cout << "You entered "
                          << num
                          << " word"
                          << ((num == 1) ? "." : "s.")
                          << '\n';
                num = 0;
            }
        });
}
```

Doesn't waste resources by tokenizing a line into a vector :)

Answer (score 0):

I would call distance

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::string line;
    while(std::getline(std::cin, line) && line != "quit")
    {
        std::stringstream  linestream(line);
        std::cout << "You entered "
                  << std::distance(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(linestream), 
                                   std::istream_iterator<std::string>())
                  << " words\n";
    }
}
```